# Moving files in batch corrupts directories on running in Windows PE

Tags: batch-file, winpe

On an industrial PC there is a recovery partition running Windows PE. On this WPE environment there are some batch scripts running that offer the user some choices. E.g. "Press 1 for this, press 2 for that", etc.

I'm currently working on an operation that includes moving and deleting files to an external drive. Using the following commands I can move and delete files:

```
::Create a new folder on the external drive
if not exist "F:\Backup\TemporaryFiles\" mkdir F:\Backup\TemporaryFiles

::Move log files
move /y "%dataVolume%\system\LogFile\*.log" "F:\Backup\TemporaryFiles\"
move /y "%dataVolume%\system\LogFile\*.gz" "F:\Backup\TemporaryFiles\"

::Delete PNG files
del "%dataVolume%\system\LogImg\*.png" /f/q

:: Reboot safely
wpeutil reboot
```

However, after rebooting both **the source directories** from which the files were moved as well as **the target directory** on the external drive **are corrupted**. Using `chkdsk` they can be restored, but of course it is not a stable state.

According to [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/521041/how-to-safely-shutdown-reboot-a-windows-pe-environment), `wpeutil reboot` can be used to safely reboot the PC and flush all data to disk. I would expect that this is enough to avoid corrupt directories, but it seems that indexing is broken after the move and/or delete operations, because `chkdsk /f` tells me that corrupt indices were restored.

Are the **move** commands not running synchronously?

I.e. is batch not waiting until move has finished before it executes the next command?

How can I ensure that my indices don't get destroyed when moving and deleting files?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue, but why not copy the files instead of moving and then delete them once copied to see if issue still occurs?

Comment: __MOVE__ is synchronous. But the file systems on Windows use read/write caches as it can be read for example in MSDN article [File Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218.aspx). That is the reason for __Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media__ item in system tray. See also Super User question [Manually flushing write cache on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/833552/).

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I will try, but how do I know that the files are completely written to the external drive?

Comment: @Mofi Yes, I know about that. I was wondering whether I can "wait" a while in batch. But neither `ping` nor `timeout` are available to create a sleep-like function on my Industrial PC. Regarding `move` being synchronous: If I `move` a file of 1 GiB size, batch would wait a few minutes (using USB 2.0) until the rather long move action is done and then go on with the execution of the script? Thanks.

Comment: Were any of the files actually in use by the system when the move was attempted? You should run `help robocopy` and familiarize yourself with its capabilities. It's been a while, but I am pretty sure `robocopy` is available on WinPE. You're probably looking for `/J` option, which copies files in unbuffered mode, possibly also `/ZB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `move` is working synchronously and `wpeutil reboot` should flush all buffers to disk, I should have been fine with what I'm doing. However, I decided to make sure that all buffers are actually flushed to disk (i.e. the USB drive), by using [sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sync) and waiting for it to return:

```
move /y "\TmpLogFile\*.gz" "%%d\Backup\TemporaryFiles\"
START /WAIT cmd /c "sync.exe" "-r -e %%d"
wpeutil reboot
```

`%%d` is holding the letter assigned to the USB drive.